# What is the purpose of the `(app)` in `require(controller)(app)`?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node, blah blah

I'm looking through some code I found, and encountered the lines

```
var app = express();
var glob = require('glob');

var controllers = glob.sync(config.root + '/app/controllers/*.js');
    controllers.forEach(function (controller) {
    require(controller)(app);
});
```

I understand that this goes and gets all the filenames of every file in `/app/controllers/` that ends with `.js`, and sticks them in an array, then iterates over each one and calls a require on it. Makes sense, and looks like a nice way of not requiring each one individually. My question is what's that last `(app)` for? I tried looking at node documentation, but there is no `require()()` function. editing out the `(app)` leaves the code working fine with no errors, but doesn't load the controllers. If I had to take a guess, is it 'multiplying' the app by the found controller? Why would `app.require(controller)` not be a suitable option?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require) is a part of node and is how modules are loaded.  When you edit out the `(app)`, it is probably still loading the controllers but because you haven't passed the `app` object over to each controller, they fail silently or return a controller object that doesn't work.

So something in the controller (probably a route being created or other similar stuff) needs to know about the `app` object and it has to be passed into the controller because `app` isn't in the global scope.  You may want to review the node docs for [module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) and [globals](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global_objects) as those will probably clear up WAY more than just this one question.

Answer (score 1):

In my estimation we will have:

```
/* some-controller-file.js */
module.exports = function (app) {
    /* do things with `app` */
}
```

So this allows you to use the created `app` inside of the controllers probably so you can attach routes.